# Write HTML received as string to browser

Tags: python, html

I have a basic HTML file which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I am receiving the file in python and storing it as a string. I want to know, is there a way I can write this out to a web browser?

The file is on my computer, so my goal is not to save it as an html file and then execute it, but rather execute this from within python to the browser.

I know that with JavaScript I can use `Document.write()` to inject content to a webpage, but that is already being done in the browser. I want to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flask`, a simple Python web framework, to serve the string:

Using `flask` (`pip install flask`):

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
s = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  </body>
 </html>
"""
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
app.run()
```

Now, can you navigate to `127:0.0.1:5000` or the equivalent IP and port specified when the app is run.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can start the server to go to that port from within the Flask call? I like this method

Comment: @tushariyer `flask` handles the routing and ports automatically. However, if you are looking for a web to open the webbrowser to the specific route, I suggest using a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</body>
</html>"""

with open('html_file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

import webbrowser, os
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('html_file.html'))
```